# How to load a class from another classloader which doesn't have a package name?

Tags: java, android, classloader, dex

I need to know how to load a class which doesn't have a package, using a different classloader (test.jar contains the classes.dex file):

```
File f = new File("/sdcard/test.jar");
final File optimizedDexOutputPath = context.getDir("outdex", 0);
DexClassLoader classLoader = new DexClassLoader(f.getAbsolutePath(), optimizedDexOutputPath.getAbsolutePath(), null, context.getClassLoader());
```

---

If "Test" class has a package:

```
package com.test;

public class Test {
    public static void test() {
        // do something
    }
}
```

This works:

```
Class<?> myClass = classLoader.loadClass("com.test.Test");
```

---

If "Test" class doesn't have a package:

```
public class Test {
    public static void test() {
        // do something
    }
}
```

This doesn't work:

```
Class<?> myClass = classLoader.loadClass("Test");
```

---

Is it possible to load a class without a package?

Comment: Do you manage to load your class in case of expanded binaries directory instead of a .jar?

Comment: Yes, you just need to create a JAR during runtime before loading them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problem to load class without package name. Check my example (Class "Test" must has no package):

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        try {
            Class<?> myClass = Test.class.getClassLoader().loadClass("Test");
            System.out.println(myClass);
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

You will got console output without exception:

class Test

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm trying to load with a different classloader. I updated my question with more details about it!

Comment: You were right, the real problem was that my class was implementing an interface which wasn't implemented on my app.